# Can I combine flock and source?

Tags: bash, flock

I'd like to source a script (it sets up variables in my shell):

```
source foo.sh args
```

But under flock so that only one instance operates at a time (it does a lot of disk access which I'd like to ensure is serialized).

```
$ source flock lockfile foo.sh args
-bash: source: /usr/bin/flock: cannot execute binary file
```

and

```
$ flock lockfile source foo.sh args
flock: source: Success
```

don't work.

Is there some simple syntax for this I'm missing? Let's assume I can't edit foo.sh to put the locking commands inside it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't `source` a script directly via `flock` because it is an external command and `source` is a shell builtin. You actually have two problems because of this:

- `flock` doesn't know any command called `source` because it's built into `bash`
- Even if `flock` could run it, the changes would not affect the state of the calling shell as you'd want with `source` because it's happening in a child process.

And, passing `flock` to `source` won't work because `source` expects a script. To do what you want, you need to lock by fd.  Here's an example

```
#!/bin/bash

exec 9>lockfile
flock 9
echo whoopie
sleep 5
flock -u 9
```

Run two instances of this script in the same directory at the same time and you will see one wait for the other.